# How can print the variable $nrr in middle of text?

Tags: laravel

$msgm = 'Pesquisa concluida com sucesso, foram econtrados', "%{$nrr}%" 'resultados';

How can print the variable $nrr in middle of text?

Comment: Perguntas e respostas aqui devem ser escritas em inglês (incluindo o título). Use http://pt.stackoverflow.com para português, por favor. (Questions and answers here must be written in English [including the title]. Please use http://pt.stackoverflow.com for Portuguese.)

Comment: Also maybe you're looking for [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [details on PHP strings in general](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: if((strlen($tpesquisa ))<4) {
            $msgm = 'Utilize pelo menos 4 caracteres para iniciar uma pesquisa';
                return view('index',compact( 'msgm'));

            }
        $produtos = Produtos::where('nome', 'like', "%{$tpesquisa}%")->get();
        $msgm = 'Pesquisa concluida com sucesso, foram econtrados', "%{$nrr}%" 'resultados';
        $nrr=count($produtos);

        return view('pesquisa',compact('produtos', 'msgm', 'nrr'));
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$msgm = "Pesquisa concluida com sucesso, foram econtrados, ".$nrr." resultados";
```

There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. for details
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php